# How can I filter only images and videos in the android Gallery?

Tags: android, filtering

How can I filter only images and videos in the android Gallery?

For Example:

```
    intent.setType("image/*");   //returns only images
    intent.setType("video/*");   //returns only videos
    intent.setType("*/*");       //returns all videos,images, audios,contacts,etc..
```

I want only images and videos. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-platform-apps/Gallery/com/android/camera/ImageGallery.java.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
intent.setType("video/*, images/*");
```

Comment: I even tried this but it is not supported in all the devices, for eg. in Galaxy Ace, it says no data found, in HTC it only shows images.